# is there a way to save the same variable in local storage but different value for each property list?

Tags: typescript, angular16

I am making real estate website using angular 16 and I am trying to add "Like" button on each of the properties that i have for sale or rent. I was able to save the variable to local storage and get the value back but my problem is it is showing the same value of likes in all properties which is wrong. It should have different number of likes for different property listed.

here is what I have in my html page:

```
<div class="card-footer">
    <div class="btn-group d-flex">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addLike($event.target)">{{likes}} Likes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Message</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my typescript file:

this is how i save the variable:

```
addLike(element:any){

    this.likes += 1;
    let data = element.textContent = this.likes;
    localStorage.setItem('numLikes',JSON.stringify(data));
    location.reload();

  }
```

and this is how i get it to show:

```
ngOnInit() {
    
    let data2:any = localStorage.getItem('numLikes');
    this.likes = JSON.parse(data2);
    ....
```